# View set cookies of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, cookies, developer-tools

I am trying to debug an iOS app without having the actual code.
It is using a ui web view, calling a website that sets cookies. I need to check which cookies are set. The problem does not appear in safari, only in the app, so I need to check the cookies of the app.

How can I do that? Is there a developer tool that can help me read the cookies similar to the safari web inspector?

Or do the developers have to use a certain framework to make the cookies readable?

Can I use xcode to debug an app - similar web inspector for safari - without having the code?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an old question but nevertheless relevant. So for the sake of posterity here's is how to connect an iOS mobile device to an OSX device to view web inspector.

https://appletoolbox.com/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/